# Why are ObjectIdentifiers sometime reused?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I was running code that looks like

```
final class Foo: Identifiable {}

let id1 = Foo().id
print("id1", id1.hashValue)

let id2 = Foo().id
print("id2", id2.hashValue)
print("id1 == id2", id1 == id2)

let foo1 = Foo()
let foo2 = Foo()
print("id3", foo1.id.hashValue)
print("id4", foo2.id.hashValue)
```

I realized that often - not always - the first two ids would be the same (same hash, same pointer), that the last two would always be different, and that the second hash value and the third one would also often - not always - be the same.

For instance this would most likely print

```
// id1, id2 and id3 are the same
id1 372028973742592862
id2 372028973742592862
id1 == id2 true
id3 372028973742592862
id4 -6512610764240591489
```

and sometimes

```
// id1 and id2 are the same
id1 682965245911293614
id2 682965245911293614
id1 == id2 true
id3 -1068884789025324935
id4 6999154593386001644
```

and more rarely

```
// all ids are different
id1 9219089083903263322
id2 6156776739104921767
id1 == id2 false
id3 -8383648492598359180
id4 483187449076408614
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the `ObjectIdentifier` is based on the object's memory address. The first two objects not being retained, Swift can reuse the memory slot for a new object. This new object then get the exact same identifier than the previous one.

The last two objects are retained, so there is no memory reuse and the ids are always different.

I find it very confusing that Swift allows for the ["unique identity"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objectidentifier) to only be unique at a given moment but not over time. This is an issue as soon as those ids are persisted after the objects are deallocated.

Comment: There are two approaches to this: sequences (hard to scale, but consecutive) and randomization (easy to scale, but not consecutive). That's why UUID is so popular.